# google ad exchange request.py run error in eclipse

Tags: python, pydev

When debugging my "google dobule click exchange testing script", it runs successfully on a `Python Terminal`, but when doing so with the `eclipse pydev IDE`, the following line give me an error:

```java
import realtime_bidding_pb2
```

The error I'm getting is

> ImportError: No module named realtime_bidding_pb2

I know this module is outsourced, but I don't know where it is or how to import it into the `eclipse pydev IDE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use unix like OS, change directory to the directory where the files requester.py, Makefile, realtime-bidding.proto (from requester.tar.gz) and execute command 'make' in shell. realtime_bidding_pb2 file will be created.

Next you get "ImportError: No module named google.protobuf". You need install python-protobuf (command 'apt-get install python-protobuf' for Ubuntu, you should be root).

Uses requester.py by command like 'python requester.py  --url= --max_qps=1 --seconds=20'.